# Adding more than one Wordpress Gutenburg block type?

Tags: customization, admin

I am currently in the process of creating a Wordpress plugin that allows extra block types to be added for creating posts. I have successfully created a wordpress block type but it doesn't work when I add two.

The following code is in a JS file.

https://pastebin.com/5GMp3aa1

When I add two block types, Wordpress's backend editor doesn't even recognise the first block. Removing the second block makes the first block type register and work. To those who are experienced in Wordpress plugin creation, what error am I making?

Comment: The contents of `MORE CODE HERE` seems important here. Can you include the actual code that’s causing the problem?

Comment: I didn't think it was important as the code within the block is functioning and working. But, I will copy and paste all of it now.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Absolutely none, I was surprised! Tell a lie, there was a few but they had nothing to do with the script itself.

Comment: What happens if you try to whittle the code down to the smallest reproducible example? Also are you using webpack/babel? Or are you writing all your React components from scratch? And by doesn't recognize, do you mean it's as if you never made the first call? Or something else? I also noticed you namespaced your blocks, I have never seen that before

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I initially posted this question I put "MORE CODE HERE" in between curly brackets because the code itself works in the first method and was asked to put more code there so I added more.

When I append another method for the same thing (a.k.a registering a new block type) it stops the first method from registering, that's all. I also used Babel to generate the ReactJS code as it is easier for me.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the pastebin code is the actual code? The second block registration code has a pretty massive typo in the first line, so much so that the entire code example generates JS syntax errors as a result

Comment: In fact the second block registration code has multiple syntax errors that crop up if I try and put the code into the browser dev tools. It looks like instead of ending the first parameter with a comma, you closed the function call, then put the second parameter afterwards dangling on its own, then didn't bother to close it properly after that either

Comment: Ok, don't worry. It's my lazy syntax errors. I just copied and pasted the code twice and it registered another block. I just screwed up my coding - I now need to rectify what I coded wrong and create a working block. Thanks for the help because I didn't think to copy and patse working code! I feel ignorant. :F

Answer (score 0):

To create a new block make the second block contain actual working code! I was silly and there was some syntax errors in the second method.